# Add value based on Category

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Fairly new to Excel but I want to make a cost sheet.

The layout is like this:

A1: Category B1: Price 
A2: Food B2: € 5,00 
A3: Utilities: B3: € 50,00 
A4: Food B4: € 10,00

Now I want to combine all the Categories that list "Food", so the total outcome will be € 15,00

What I found was IF=(A:A="Food";Sum(B:B))
But this returns me all the values in B:B, so the outcome is € 65,00. 
Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the SUMIF function.
`SUMIF(A:A,"Food",B:B)` will do what you want.

You can do it with just SUM and IF, but you have to enter it as an array formula.
Try entering `SUM(IF(A:A="Food",B:B,0))`, but hold down `CTRL` and `SHIFT` when you press `ENTER`, so that it is displayed like this: `{=SUM(IF(A:A="Food",B:B,0))}` (do not type the curly braces; Excel will add them automatically when you enter an array formula).

Comment: Works perfectly!